# Confusion about the Reparametrization Lemma

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I am confused about this Lemma in Bredon:

"Let $\phi _1$ and $\phi _2$ be maps $(I,\delta I) \to (I,\delta I)$ which are equal on $\delta I$.
Let $F: X \times I \to Y $ be a homotopy and let $G_i(x,t) = F(x,\phi_i (t))$ for i=1,2 then $G_1 \simeq G_2 $"

What i find confusing about this is that if I choose $\phi _1,\phi _2 $ to be the function given by $t \to 0$ on $I$, then I get that every homotopy $F$ is homotopic to the function $C$ which is defined by $C(x,t)=F(x,0)$ because $F(x,\phi _1(t)) = F(x,0) = C(x,\phi_2 (t)) $ which means that every homotopy is homotopic to a constant homotopy. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You choose $\phi _1,\phi _2 $ to be the same map. It is only normal they correspond to the same $G$. I don't see how you conclusion follows.

Comment: Yeah you are right, thanks for the help!